# ¿Cómo borrar registros en cascada de tres tablas?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, delete

(Nesecito la consulta "DELETE FROM")

Tengo las tablas **Customers**, **Orders**, **Order_items** y nesecito hacer un delete (que borre todo) de las 3 segun el id de **Customers**. Aqui les dejo una foto de las tablas y como se comunican.
[image: Tablas a cuales hay que hacer DELETE]

Como vemos tenemos el **Customer.id** que equivale a **Orders.Customer_id** ahora tengo las tablas *Customers* y *Orders* pero falta borrar **Order_items** para eso tenemos que buscar en la tabla **Orders** el id que equivale a **Order_items.order_id**.

**Les explico mejor**:

Obtengo la de la url el valor "*ID*" digamos que es "*11*" que seria de la tabla **CUSTOMERS** ahora quiero que busque y borre los datos de la tabla **ORDERS** con el *id* de **CUSTOMERS** (*11*) que esta ubicado en **CUSTOMER_ID**. Ahora le toca a **ORDER_ITEMS** que para buscar los datos tiene que ser con el *id* de **ORDERS**. Que estaria ubicado en **ORDER_ID** de la tabla **ORDER_ITEMS**.

Anteriormente realize un INNER JOIN con estas tablas no se si les servira para entender mejor:

```
SELECT * FROM customers 
INNER JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.customer_id 
INNER JOIN order_items ON orders.id = order_items.order_id 
WHERE orders.customer_id = $idOrder*
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer un `ALTER` a tu tabla de **Order_items** y **orders** de modo que la llave foránea de estas tablas este configurada como `ON DELETE CASCADE`, el código quedaría así:

```sql
 -- SUPONGAMOS QUE ASI CREASTE LAS TABLAS.
 
 CREATE TABLE customers (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
 NOMBRE VARCHAR(20)
 );
 
 CREATE TABLE orders (
 id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
 customers_id INT,
 CONSTRAINT FK_Customers_Orders_RESTRICT FOREIGN KEY (customers_id) REFERENCES Customers(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT);
 
 CREATE TABLE order_items (
 id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
 order_id INT,
 CONSTRAINT FK_Order_OrderItem_RESTRICT FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT);
 
 -- DEBES ELIMINAR LA LLAVE FOREANEA DE ESTA MANERA DE LAS DOS TABLAS Y LUEGO AGREGAR 
 OTRA CON LA RESTRICCION "ON DELETE CASCADE"
 ALTER TABLE orders DROP FOREIGN KEY  FK_Customers_Orders_RESTRICT;
 ALTER TABLE orders ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Customers_Orders_CASCADE FOREIGN KEY(customers_id) REFERENCES Customers(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
 
 ALTER TABLE order_items DROP FOREIGN KEY  FK_OrderItem_RESTRICT;
 ALTER TABLE order_items ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Customers_Orders_CASCADE FOREIGN KEY(customers_id) REFERENCES Customers(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Al poner el `ON DELETE CASCADE` estas indicando que al **eliminar el registro de la tabla contenedora de la llave primaria** también se **elimine el registro de la tabla que contiene la llave foránea.**

Espero te sea de ayuda amigo.

Comment: Por favor corrige el codigo ya que no se ejecuta correctamente y no lo entiendo. Tienes la imagen para poder guiarte.

Comment: Es que el código que yo escribí fue solo un ejemplo con tablas cortas, a manera de explicación para realizar una eliminación a como la quieres hacer. Pero si lo deseas puedo adjuntar una captura para que lo veas mas claro.

Comment: O es en PHP que querés la solución?, eso es lo que no entendí. Eso que yo hice es en MySQL.